# Django-nose cannot find tests in folders

Tags: python, django, nose, django-nose

I know there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but I can't quite find one that matches my situation.

I'm working on an app built by someone else and have been adding tests.

The folder structure is like so:

```
my_project
├── apps
│   ├── app1
|       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── tests.py
│   └── app2
│   └── app3
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

However, when I run `python manage.py test`, I get 0 tests run. Running the individual apps (`python manage.py test app1`) works when django-nose isn't installed, but works without django-nose.

Comment: Try manully import tests from Python interpreter command line and see there are no import errors.

Comment: Tried: import my_project and then dir(my_project), but I don't see any of my apps in there.

Comment: Import tests, not the project.

Comment: I tried import tests and didn't see any errors.

Comment: Ok then it is something else.